# SQL trigger with WHEN and UPDATE statements

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm writing the following code which is supposed to increment by 1 'likecount' from the 'song' table after an insert has been made into the 'ecoute' table.
Before doing so, the trigger checks if the boolean 'likked' from the new insertion is 'true'. If so, then the UPDATE goes on. Else, nothing happens.

```
CREATE TRIGGER likked AFTER INSERT ON ecoute
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.likked)
BEGIN
    UPDATE songs
    SET songs.likecount = songs.likecount +1
    WHERE songs.id = NEW.songid
END
```

MySQL answered :

```
#1064 - Syntax error near 'WHEN (NEW.likked)
BEGIN
    UPDATE songs
    SET songs.likecount = songs.like' at line 3
```

**Notes** :
Until now I've tried to create differents JOIN because I thought the problem was I call for NEW table while updating SONGS table, but the answer from MySQL remains the same.

Comment: I am simply not aware of `when` being part of the create trigger syntax in MySQL.

Comment: I'm probably wrong then. I admit to be a complete beginner with coding.
What should I use instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a IF THEN test to check the value of likked

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER likked AFTER INSERT ON ecoute
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.likked=1 THEN 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE songs
            SET songs.likecount = songs.likecount +1
            WHERE songs.id = NEW.songid;
        END; 
    END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you !
Another mistake i made was the way i checked for NEW.likked. I did not know it worked to write "=1" for a boolean. Thanks !

Comment: I expected that it was a Boolean indeed. Proud to have beaten @GordonLinoff, for once :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER likked AFTER INSERT ON ecoute
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.likked = 1 THEN
        UPDATE songs
            SET songs.likecount = songs.likecount +1
            WHERE songs.id = NEW.songid
    END IF;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: damn... you beat me again :-)

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be exactly what i'm trying to do. But for an unknown reason, MySQL returns "an unexpected error happened" when i try to execute it.

Comment: The (NEW.likked) part bothered it. Using NEW.likked = 1 instead works.
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Benjamin.P . . . What is the datatype of `likked`?  I'm really surprised the `=` is necessary in MySQL.